# How to loop ObjectStorage items on fluid from typo3

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have a like feature on my plugin where a user can like an idea, for that I have a mm table where I relate the idea and the user. I want to disable or enable the "like" button depending on if the user has liked the idea or not already.
When I call the $this->votedUsers from my model my fluid template gets this. What is this? Is not an array? How can I loop this to check if the user has liked the idea already.

This is what my $this->votedUsers property from my Idea model contains and I want to loop to check if that FrontendUser has liked the idea already and disable or enable de button.

[image]

This is how <f:debug>{_all}</f:debug> looks like

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this inside your idea model:

```php
public function isLikedByCurrentUser(): bool
{
    $currentUser = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)
        ->get(FrontendUserRepository::class)
        ->findByUid($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid']);
    if ($currentUser) {
        return $this->votedUsers->contains($currentUser);
    }

    return false;
}
```

After that you can check it in Fluid via `<f:if condition="{idea.likedByCurrentUser}"> ... </f:if>`.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to do it in the model. I have no idea how that code works tho, I'm new with typo3. I'm always getting false. Even when $currentUser has the correct FrontendUser, my mm table has the correct relations between them, and $this->votedUsers does contains that same user.

Comment: Can you debug what is in `$currentUser`? Is it the same FrontendUser? Looking at uid and the class name.

Comment: What TYPO3 version do you use?

Comment: $curranUser is a FrontendUser model type. Last pic is $currentUser.
I'm using 10.4

Comment: Looks like the votedUsers are of type `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser` while your currentUser is `Hebotek\HeboIdeas\Domain\Model\FrontendUser`

Comment: You both guys saved me hours of trying and shame haha, thanks!